Opposite results between one-side confidence interval and one-side hypothesis test for one proportion each other?
I'm trying an example in PennState STAT 415 (Example 9-2)

Method 1: a right-tailed hypothesis test

In short, the observed sample proportion is $\hat{p}=\dfrac{104}{590}=0.176$. The null hypothesis is $H_0 \colon p_0 = 0.14$, and the alternative hypothesis is $H_A \colon p > 0.14$. The significance level is $\alpha = 0.01$, so the critical region is $ > 2.326$. After calculating the test statistic $Z$, which is $2.52$ ($=\dfrac{0.176-0.14}{\sqrt{\dfrac{0.14(0.86)}{590}}}$), the null hypotheis is rejected since $2.52 > z_{0.01}$. It means that the true proportion is greater than $0.14$.

Method 2: one-side confidence interval for the sample proportion
$\hat{p}$

The formula for the one-side confidence interval (lower bound to infinity) of unknown true $p$ (not necessily $p_0$ in Method 1) is: $[\hat{p}-z_{\alpha} \sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}, +\infty)$, which is: $p \geq 0.176 - 2.326\times\sqrt{\dfrac{0.176(0.824)}{590}} = 0.1395$. Because the assumed true $p$ ($0.14$) is in the interval of $[0.1395, +\infty)$, we cannot say that the sample proportion means a greater true proportion. This is the opposite conclusion with the Method 1.
Why do the conclusions by two method contradict each other?

Your test is calculated under the null, i.e. using $p_0=0.14$ for the variance rather than $\hat p$.

And you didn't invert the acceptance region correctly.

@PBulls But in the calculation of a confidence interval of the sample proportion, we don't know other things except the $\hat p$ and sample size $n$. We don't know $p_0$, which is used in the hypothesis test.

@User1865345 Could you explain a bit about "didn't invert the acceptance region correctly"?

@PBulls For example, in this website (https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/5/5.1), it is said that "... replace the population proportions ($p$) that appear in the endpoints of the interval with sample proportions ($\hat p$) to get an (approximate) confidence interval for $p$".

@TX that may well be, but that gives you an answer to a different question (it is not the CI that corresponds to the hypothesis test). The test asks, what is the probability of these data assuming $p=0.14$ (which implies a known variance -- look at the denominator of your test statistic). The CI approximately answers, what $p$ might these data be compatible with (using an estimated variance).

This is somewhat akin to comparing a continuous $z$-test to a $t$-based CI or vice versa (of course these will differ to some decimal when $\nu < \infty$), only the latter doesn't have a direct equivalent in the binary case because mean and variance aren't independent. But one of them still treats variance as known/fixed while the other doesn't.

@User1865345 Now I see what you mean. I misused the $p$ in the question in method 1 and method 2, which should be written as $p_0$ in method 1. I have changed them.

@TX since I was writing the answer when you posted yours, I posted it anyway but with general pointers for your further study.

$\bullet$ As PBulls noted, OP used two different things in the hope of those two yielding the same conclusion.
OP used the Wald confidence interval which was different of what one gets inverting the acceptance region of the corresponding test above.
Retaining $p$ and solving for it would lead to the Wilson confidence interval, which is better than the Wald score interval in many ways but more importantly it is boundary-respecting.
$\bullet$ Broadening the discussion, in discrete cases, to obtain a given confidence coefficient, randomized confidence sets are used, and are obtained from a corresponding randomized test procedure by incorporating a uniform variable on $[0, 1]$ independent of the sample. An illustration on binomial proportion has been discussed in Shao's Mathematical Statistics book.
$\bullet$ Finally much has been written about the confidence intervals of binomial proportion. The Wikipedia article could be a good place to start.

As @PBulls suggests, the method 1 or 2 uses different $p$ ($p_0$ or $\hat p$) in the formula, which makes them answer two different questions. There is a disccusion about using $p_0$ or $\hat p$ in the formula of the test statistic $Z$ at the end of Section 9.3 in the same STAT415 lesson.
In short, if we use $\hat p$ in the test statistic formula, then the results of the confidence interval will be consistent with the hypothesis test decision.
Take the example in the question, when using $\hat p$ in the formula, the $Z$ value is: $\dfrac{0.176-0.14}{\sqrt{\dfrac{0.176\times 0.824}{590}}} = 2.296$. Since $2.296 < z_{0.01}$, we cannot reject the null hypothesis. This conclusion is now consistent with the conclusion by confidence interval.
